# How to efficiently store timeseries data

Tags: c++, time-series

I have a sequence of timestamped updates with the timestamps monotonically increasing

```
<t1,d1> , <t2,d2> , <t3, d3> .... <tn, dn>
```

I need to store this data. I know beforehand the max time delta that I care about.
So say the time delta I care about is T. so, I only need to store all the most recent updates that are not more than T units older than tn.

I would like to store them in the sorted fashion that they are given to me.

So to summarize, I am looking at storing a sorted sequence where I can efficiently delete the earlier elements. Something like a C++ dequeue.

Any suggestions on how to efficiently find the cutoff element beyond which I can delete all the older entries?

Comment: You want "Something like a C++ dequeue" so use `std::deque`.

Comment: @AnastasiyaAsadullayeva  I know the bounds only in time units. But not in terms of the number of updates I can receive.  So a circular buffer will not work.

Comment: so, essentially, u have a time interval(t1-tn) and then u have a data series for that interval.?

Comment: The data you are receiving is already sorted, right?

Comment: Why not store the data in a time-series database? Or does the data have to be in memory?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a circular buffer. When you are about to add a new datapoint, check if the value you are about to overwrite is old enougj to delete. If it is, go ahead and overwrite. Otherwise, reallocate the buffer to be, say, twice as large, and copy the data pointer into the new buffer.

The reallocation and copying could be a bit timeconsuming, but the total impact will be limited by the fact that the algorithm is basically amortized constant time.

If you really need to, you can spread the copying out by only copying a fixed number of elements from the old buffer to the new. You have to move that number of elements with each new datapoint. As long as the number is at least 2, you will end up copying all the old data before the new buffer is filled with incoming data.

Comment: Why use a circular buffer when the number of entries in a given quantum is potentially unbounded? A `deque` amortizes memory allocation overhead (allocating blocks at a time, with only the first and last block being incompletely filled), and never involves a mass copy of data (which expanding a circular buffer would). Yes, clever code could make the circular buffer expansion not cause massive bursts of work, but it's still far more complicated than using a `deque`.

Comment: @shadowranger: The advantage of the deque is that there is a standard library implementation, so tautologically the circular buffer is more work. However, it has many advantages. To start with, you can delete lazily which is a big win. Also, you have better locality of reference. And the dequeue will be constantly doing new allocations, while the circular buffer will reach a peak size and stay there. Of course, all of that could be wrong. Only benchmarking with a particular application will let us know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is a queue that on arrival of a new element may remove a few oldest ones. I am also going to assume that you need random access to all elements.

So you need a first-in first-out queue and after every add operation remove the oldest element until the oldest will be recent enough.

And how to get a FIFO queue with random access? There is `std::deque` in STL which does exactly that.

In my experience `std::deque` is surprisingly inefficient though, probably due to the bad caching behaviour. It wouldn't matter for most projects but this question was specifically about efficiency.
So if you really care about efficiency you can use a `std::vector` + an iterator to the logical beginning. So anytime you want to remove the oldest element you would just increment the iterator. The catch is that this way you would never actually remove the elements. This can be solved by checking if the number of logically removed elements in the vector exceeds half its size and then rebuilding a vector from only the necessary ones. If there is an upper bound on the number of elements in your queue you can optimize it further by using a static size array instead of a vector.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `multimap` of `tuple`s for that.

Comment: Ouch this is going to be way less efficient than using a plain deque.

Answer (score 0):

A C++ dequeue is the [`<deque>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). You could also use [`<list>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), but that's usually only beneficial if you might be iterating and deleting from the middle of the collection; if you just append and pop from the ends, a `deque` is much more efficient on both memory and speed.